# Support for Spengo auth scheme support for netty HttpClient similar to Apache HttpClient

Tags: reactor-netty

We need to connect to some component via proxy, and this proxy works by kerberos auth. We need to do something like below:

````
credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null), use_jaas_creds);
Registry authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.create().register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory(true)).build();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
// set our proxy - httpclient doesn't use ProxySelector
.setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy))
.setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(creds).build();```

We are not seeing any solution to run something like above

Expecting to have Spengo support with netty HttpClient
````